# Regular expression that filters numbers and the "/" character

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have these filters in my app:

[image: Filters]

- S/M
- L/XL
- XXL
- XL
- L
- M
- S
- XS

And i use the regular expression: `/^([0-9/])*$/`

I need the sizes that have the `/` character to be removed from the list. What regular expression can I use?

Comment: Use: `^[LMSX]+/[LMSX]+$`

Comment: you can match a literal `/` by escaping it in the regexp as `\/`. for example, `/\//.test("L/XL")` returns `true`, `/\//.test("S")` returns `false`. you can use `sizes.filter(s => !/\//.test(s))` to filter an entire list

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to filter out the sizes with a slash in them:

```
sizes.filter(item => !item.match(/\//))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the chars before the `/` and optionally match `/` and capture the chars after that.

```
^([SLXM]+)(?:\/([SLXM]+))?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/83KBDw/1)

Note that the character class `[SLXM]+` can match mixed (possibly non existing) sizes.

In the replacement use group 1 and group 2.

```js
const regex = /^([SLXM]+)(?:\/([SLXM]+))?$/;
["S/M",
  "L/XL",
  "XXL",
  "XL",
  "L",
  "M",
  "S",
  "XS"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(regex, "$1$2")));
```